# django project nginx: connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream ubuntu server on Digital Ocean

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, python-3.x, nginx

help me please, i use django + gunicorn + nginx and i get error
nginx: connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
I think the problem is a 9000 port? how to solve this problem?
[502 Bad Gateway](http://45.55.254.196/)

## /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2015/05/07 04:57:28 [error] 11439#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 5.178.184.108, server: 45.55.254.196, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/favicon.ico", host: "45.55.254.196"
```

## sudo netstat -plntu

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28846/nginx     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      946/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      28846/nginx     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      946/sshd
```

## my config

## /etc/nginx/sites-available/hotel

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name 45.55.254.196;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/hotel/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/hotel/static;
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

## /etc/init/gunicorn.conf

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project"
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /home/django

exec gunicorn \
    --name=hotel \
    --pythonpath=hotel \
    --bind=127.0.0.1:9000 \
    --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py \
    hotel.wsgi:application
```

## /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from os import environ

def max_workers():
    return cpu_count() * 2 + 1

max_requests = 1000
worker_class = 'gevent'
workers = max_workers()
```

Comment: what happens if you connect directly to the 9000 port ?

Comment: @Pixou tanks for replying, I tried to connect telnet 127.0.0.1 9000 and get result Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
I think the problem is this, do you have another opinion? what is the problem?

Comment: so it means you have an issue with gunicorn, not nginx. I'm really not an expert in gunicorn, but I would look at the logs. Maybe you can also try to run a django dev server to check that your django is running smoothly

Comment: @Pixou when i run this command "gunicorn hotel.wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.1:9000" it works

Comment: then I guess daniel's answer should work !

Comment: @Pixou bro still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77191/discussion-between-lhackg-and-pixou).

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have started gunicorn. Since you've made an init script for it, you should do `sudo start gunicorn`.

Comment: If it is not running gunicorn hotel.wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.1:9000 get error 502 Bad Gateway http://45.55.254.196/